# How to bind mysql server to a certain IP?

Tags: mysql5.5, my.cnf

In remote mysql 5.5 server I tried to add

```
bind-address = 11.22.33.44
```

Where bind-address = 127.0.0.1 has commented out and 11.22.33.44 is the Ip of the web server communicating with the database server. But after adding the line mysql does not restart. Any ideas to fix this? Also, I'd like to know other ways to harden the connection.

Comment: Are you trying to limit which remote hosts can connect to your MySQL server?  `bind-address` is not the right way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the web server the same physical server than the database server? `bind-address` should be an address that is assigned to your server -- if `ifconfig` lists the address, then you can use it for MySQL. You can't just blindly pick some IP and put that as `bind-address`, no sir.

**EDIT:** It seems you understand `bind-address` completely wrong.

1) Put your database server IP address as `bind-address`.

2) With MySQL `GRANT` statements, allow your web server IP (or DNS name...) to access certain database as certain user with the privileges you want to grant, for example

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON mywpinstallation.* 
TO 'someusername'@'yourwebservername.yourdomain.com' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'supersecretpassword'
```

3) Configure your web application to contact your database server as the user you just granted.

4) Make sure your database server is not reachable from the outside world; use the firewall you have, or if you somehow don't have a separate firewall, just use `iptables`.

Comment: Janne, the database server is a separate physical server whose IP is 11.22.33.44. So how can I bind it mysql server to webserver's IP?

Comment: Domains in MySQL auth can be tricky.  Better to stick to IP addresses.  The wildcard `%` is allowed.

Comment: @Ladadadada: Sure, the `%` is allowed but bit too wide open for my taste. With the simple setups domains work OK, but of course if the web server has multiple domains set, things change...